# Simple loop doesn't work

Tags: matlab, loops, comparison

This is crazy, have been stuck on this MATLAB code for ages. What I've got is the following:

```
for i = 1 : 0.1 : 5

    index = find(someArray == i)
    %do stuff

end
```

Now the first time the loop runs, when i = 1, index returns a correct value (e.g. 45). Now, the second time the loop runs, index gets set to an empty set of brackets - '[]' ...! (The same happens for the rest of the iterations).

This is crazy because starting the loop at 1.1 sets index to a logical numerical value. In fact, every iteration should set a logical value for index using find. So it's like 'find' doesn't like being used inside loops or something....

Any ideas or help is much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem using the find function in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669942/problem-using-the-find-function-in-matlab)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that `someArray` contains the value `1.1`? This could simply be a problem with floating point precision. There's lots of information about this sort of thing on the web, including:

http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/news_notes/pdf/Fall96Cleve.pdf

http://floating-point-gui.de/

http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1108.html

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-12135.html?#bqxyrhp

Comment: Thanks. I think you saved my sanity. So for example, (0.3 == 0.1*3) evaluates to false... wow, not exactly intuitive.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of digital arithmetic.  It ain't the same as you learned in grade school!!!  Good luck.